# php regular expression preg_match get css classes,ids and tags

Tags: php, css, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have following css code

```
thead 
{
    /*some code*/
}
tr,img {
    /*some code*/
}
@page {
    /*some code*/
}
p,h2,h3 {
    /*some code*/
}
h2,h3 {
    /*some code*/
}
img {
    /*some code*/
}
```

I want all css related to img using php regular expression preg_match or preg_replace.
For example if I searched for img, following output will have to show

```
tr,img {
    /*some code*/
}
img {
    /*some code*/
}
```

php code is

```
$str='img{  } .class_class { } #awesome_id{ }';
$search='img';
$str = preg_replace("~{(."$search".)}~s","", $str);
$arr = array_filter(explode(' ',$str));
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Could you provide the attempts, that you already made in the question?

Comment: If there's no [nested {}](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/23241/126902) try something [like this](https://regex101.com/r/rK1xJ5/1) with [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
$re = '/.*\bimg\b.*?{(?s:.*?)}/i'; 
$str = "thead \n{\n    /*some code*/\n}\ntr,img {\n    /*some code*/\n}\n@page {\n    /*some code*/\n}\np,h2,h3 {\n    /*some code*/\n}\nh2,h3 {\n    /*some code*/\n}\nimg {\n    /*some code*/\n}"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iA8lU8/1)

Explanation:

- `.*` - matches any characters but a newline, 0 or more times before
- `\bimg\b` - a literal whole word `img` (case-insensitively due to `i` flag)
- `.*?` - any characters but a newline, 0 or more but as few as possible
- `{` - a literal `{`
- `(?s:.*?)` - any character *even a newline* (due to `(?s:)` inline flag) but as few as possible
- `}` - Literal `}`.